# Using Audio in a Windows 7 HTML Desktop App

Tags: html, audio, titanium, tidesdk

I've seen several topics here kind of skirting around the issue, so maybe I'm just not understanding. I've developed a simple app loading and firing audio events in jQuery. Works like a dream in Chrome as you can see here

http://dev.planetstudio.com/coke/FSSimulator/

So I was planning on wrapping it in TideSDK - audio doesn't fire - javascript breaks. Then I tried app.js - audio doesn't fire. I tried .wav, .mp3 and .ogg files. Any help would GREATLY be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out TideSDK works well, but we had to use the Titanium API here

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/#!/api/Titanium.Media.Sound

I would imagine it's the same for app.js.

Answer (score 0):

@Jacksnap13 you can refer to TideSDK API documentation [here](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/). This link contains comprehensive documentation of various TideSDK native APIs available for development.